# How to change a module's directory in Zend Framework 2 from /vendor to /module?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to customize a module that I installed using composer, and it is now in `/vendor`. When I copy it in `/module` directory, it won't be recognized anymore. Here is the file  `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, that I added this into it:

```
return array(
    'myModule\\Module' => $vendorDir . '/../module/myModule/Module.php',
);
```

and after that it was working. But the problem is that whenever I run `php comnposer.phar install` that file is overwritten and again I have to update that file.

It seems that I am doing it wrong. So, What's the correct way to copy a module from vendor directory to module directory without loosing the functionality?

Regards

**Edit**: I want to fork the package and edit that fork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can change where composer installs things to by specifying a `vendor-dir` in your app's `composer.json`, see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#config But this would affect all composer-installed packages, including (presumably) your installation of Zend Framework itself.

I would recommend you just leave the vendor folder as-is and let Composer do its thing.

**Edit**: Okay, if you want to fork a project, it's best to make changes outside of your app. Checkout a copy of your fork, make any changes you need and commit them. Then run `composer update` in your app to bring in the updated version.

If you need to test your changes in the app before committing them, that can be a bit fiddly. Personally I would either symlink to the checkout elsewhere on the file system (temporarily, just to get it working). Or edit the files in vendor just to figure out what changes you need to make, then apply those changes again to your separate forked project. There may be a better way though.

Comment: I want to change this module, I don't want to loos my editings each time I update with composer

Comment: You can't change files in packages installed by Composer.

Comment: He actually wants to fork the project...which would have been hard to guess from the question.

Comment: Okay, that's a bit different, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to ask this question before trying to solve this problem:

> Why i need to move this directory to another place?

Editing / modifying / moving any file or directory which located under the `vendor` folder or incorporating them to your awesome application's module/library/whatever folder by copy & paste is not a good practice. Composer won't like that.

To customize a library code, create your own module (or library) folder and properly extend composer-installed 3rd party library classes which needs to provide more or different functionality.

Comment: Sorry for my bad questioning. I edited my question. I want to fork a module, and edit that fork.

Comment: Is that module hosted on github?

Comment: It is, but I don't want to host my edited module there.

Comment: Oh i think you're trying to do something strange.

Comment: What strange! I just want to be able to edit a module for myself!

Comment: Problem is starting on when you also want to hide your editings from github. Whereas composer perfectly integrates 3rd party or custom repositories with your app: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs I think extending and using related classes is way to go.

Comment: Why not simply remove this module from your `composer.json` after moving it to `module` ? After that, just add it in your `config/application.config.php` and it will be recognized if the module implements `AutoloaderProviderInterface`.